# Can't animate node of scene using ARKit (ARKit + CoreLocation)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, nodes

I am trying to add an animation to each of the nodes in my scene. One question I have is, in the hierarchy - which node do I add the animation to. I figured it is the node that is represented by what you are actually seeing, which would be the mesh object...but I have a node that is holding two lights and the mesh object...would animating that one work too?

Here is my code - I am using a delegate method to wait until the scene is populated, and then I try to traverse the nodes of the scene and add the animation:

```
func sceneLocationViewDidSetupSceneNode(sceneLocationView: SceneLocationView, sceneNode: SCNNode) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        animation.fromValue = 100.0
        animation.toValue = 0.0
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity

        print("\(sceneNode) name name name name name" )
        for node in sceneNode.childNodes {
            for nodeInner in node.childNodes {
                for nodeInnermost in nodeInner.childNodes {
                    if (nodeInnermost.name?.localizedStandardContains("ship"))! {
                        print(nodeInnermost.childNodes.first ?? "FIRST DOESNT EXIST")
                        nodeInnermost.childNodes.first?.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "opac")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It isn't working at all, no change in opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = vc2
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    planeNode.opacity = 0
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 4

        planeNode.opacity = 1
        planeNode.position.z = -0.2
    }
 return node
```